# Asp.Net MVC How to test that the view rendered

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

HI there

I was wondering if there is a better way of testing that a view has rendered in MVC.

I was thinking perhaps I should render the view to a string but perhaps there are simpler methods?

Basically what I want to know if that the view for a given action has rendered without errors 
I m already testing  the view model but I want to see that rendering the view giving a correct **ViewData.Model** works

Comment: I've seen a couple of questions on the same topic already [Can we unit test View (‘V’) of MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005819/can-we-unit-test-view-v-of-mvc) and [Unit Testing the Views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151794/unit-testing-the-views) You can also look at [this](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/06/11/integration-testing-your-aspnet-mvc-application/) post from Steve Sanderson's blog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) TestHelpers library to perform assertions that a particular view is being returned from your action:

```
var sampleController = new SampleController();
sampleController.New().AssertViewRendered().ForView("New").WithViewData<SomeModel>();
```

To make assertions to ensure you are returning the correct data to the view, pull the model from the `ActionResult`:

```
var result = (ViewResult)sampleController.New();
((SomeModel)result.ViewData.Model).SomeProperty.ShouldNotBeNull();
```

This is as far as your unit testing should go.

For end-to-end automated functional/GUI testing you might want to think about using a tool like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can enable views compilation for your project. In this way the project won't compile unless you fix the issues. Edit this line in the .csproj file:

`<MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>` by using true instead of false

I you can also use ELMAH (install it view NuGet) and you can receive detailed errors by email (including YSOD).

[Source](http://forums.asp.net/t/1659338.aspx)