# How to do unit test for view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-views

Is there any way that can I write a unit test for Views in my ASP.NET MVC application?

I need to validate the button names, title, etc. stuff using such tests.

Comment: WatiN is the only way I can think of, however I typically think of that more as a UI or integration test than a unit test.

Comment: thanks Brook, do we have any article on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit Testing the Views?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151794/unit-testing-the-views)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've used [Coded-UI Tests for ASP.NET web applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286681.aspx). If you have the appropriate Visual Studio version, this may be on option. Ideally for MVC you can also write a lot of these tests against the controllers, which is baked in, but since you asked about Views I'm sharing the Coded UI link