# ASP.NET MVC 3 Precompile

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, preload

When I first request pages from my ASP.NET MVC 3 website it appears to suffer a delay, but on subsequent requests it is instantaneous.  I have no caching on pages so the second request is pulled from the server.  Is there any way to preload the whole app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I precompile my ASP.NET MVC application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336205/can-i-precompile-my-asp-net-mvc-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to: Precompile ASP.NET Web Site Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227972.aspx)

Comment: ASP.NET MVC projects are web application projects so this would not apply.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new [Auto-Start](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) feature in IIS 7.5 and ASP.NET 4.0 which allows you to load all application sin memory when the server starts thus avoiding the delay. For all previous versions you could schedule an automated request when the server starts in order to load the application in memory so that subsequent requests be faster.