# Forcing Visual Studio To Check .ASPX Pages When Compiling

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Is it possible to have Visual Studio check .aspx pages for errors when compiling? For example, if I have a Web Form with this control:

```
<asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" OnClick="CancelButton_Click" Text="Cancel" />
```

If **CancelButton_Click** does not exist in the code behind, have VS throw an error when compiling the application.  Currently it still compiles, but throws an error at run time. Is this possible?  I realize compile time would greatly increase, but it would be helpful catching problems before run time.  I thought I read about the ability to do this with Asp.Net MVC views, but cannot find the link.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108405/how-can-i-compile-asp-net-aspx-pages-before-loading-them-with-a-webserver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you have to compile using a [deployment project](http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-418.aspx) and uncheck "allow this site to be updatable"  This compiles just about everything except for a few minor edgecases like xml-serialization.

As you have discovered, when you compile with F5, you are really only compiling about half of your code and the rest compiles on first request.