# Force Visual Studio to fail compile for syntax errors in aspx/ascx pages for ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012

This is something I should really know how to do but I've never figured it out

How can I force Visual Studio to fail a compile based on what would ultimately be compile/syntax errors in ascx/aspx pages?

For example I could put the following into an ASPX page and the site would compile just fine, but obviously fall over if I visited this page;

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <% if (true) { %>
    <% if (true) { %>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 7):

Ah just found this in the "related" questions to the right;
[How can I compile Asp.Net Aspx Pages before loading them with a webserver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108405/how-can-i-compile-asp-net-aspx-pages-before-loading-them-with-a-webserver)

which links to;
http://mikehadlow.blogspot.ie/2008/05/compiling-aspx-templates-using.html

So I've added the following as a post-build event to my project;

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler -v / -p "$(SolutionDir)$(ProjectName)"
```

and it works like a treat!

Comment: It works, but it adds a lot of time to the build if you have a large application. I only do this once in a while as a "reality check" or after a major refactoring operation.