# Add Assembly (in Web.Config) required for assembly in GAC

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Please see the code below (Image Hander):

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="com.Genie.PresentationLayer.Web.ImageHandler1" %>
Imports com.Genie.BusinessLogicLayer

Namespace com.Genie.PresentationLayer.Web
    Public Class ImageHandler1
        Inherits ImageHandler
        Private p1 as Person    
        Public Sub New()

        End Sub
end class
end namespace
```

com.Genie.BusinessLogicLayer was added to the GAC today.  The application produces a runtime error when it gets to the Image Handler: 'Type Person is not defined'.  Adding an assembly to the web.config as follows resolves the problem:

```
<assemblies>
        <add assembly="BusinessLogicLayer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a"/>
</assemblies>
```

Why do I have to amend the web.config? I thought 'Add Assembly' was for website projects that do not use MSBuild (and therefore do not have 'References').  This is a web application project.

Comment: Are you sure that the Log4Net assembly reference in't in your `App.Config ` file in Winforms project?

Comment: ASP.NET uses the GAC just as a WinForms app. The actual assembly loading logs (see Fusion logging) or Process Monitor will tell you more about why it can't load the assembly. Perhaps a different version is in your bin directory.

Comment: @VMAtm, yes I am.  There is another assembly I have installed in the GAC (in house developed assembly) and this is not in the app.config either.  Is 'Add Assembly' only necessary for web clients (ASP.NET)?

Comment: ASP.NET see the GAC contents as well as WinForms application, but it does a local copy in temporary folder for itself. May be there is a problem with permissions for your application pool identity for an ASP.NET site.

Comment: @CodeCaster, it is loading the assembly i.e. I can use the assembly from the app.  There is just no reference to it (add assembly).

Comment: @CodeCaster, there are no runtime errors.  The ASP.NET app is a web application and not a website.

Comment: @CodeCaster, sorry I thought I was clear.  Please see the last paragraph of the question (I have justed added).

Comment: @CodeCaster, both applications work perfectly.  There is no error.  I have amended the last paragraph of the question again.  Is that clearer?

Comment: @CodeCaster, I see runtime errors if I do not add the assemblies to 'add assembly' for assemblies that are in the GAC (for the web app only).  For example, 'Type 'ILog' is not defined.'

Comment: @CodeCaster, I have added an update to my question.  Hope it is clearer what I am asking.

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Include all relevant details.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I have amended the question again after more debugging.  I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The references you add to a project are used when the project is compiled, but an ASPX page or ASHX handler is compiled when it is first requested. At this time the references are lost, so you'll need to provide them yourself.

The alternative would be [precompiling your ASPX pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108405/how-can-i-compile-asp-net-aspx-pages-before-loading-them-with-a-webserver), causing the error to be caught at compiletime as opposed to runtime, or moving the code to codebehind so your project's references will be used.

Comment: That explains why I do not see the error when I 'publish' the web application to IIS Server.  When I access the webpage on the IIS Server that accesses the Handler; the Handler is already compiled.  Do you agree?